# nlp - How do I identify if a part of sentence is an answer to Who, What, How or Why?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to assign every word in a sentence a role: Actor, Predicate, Who, What, Where, When, How or Why.

For example, "The robot brought me an orange juice" should be tagged like "The/*Actor*  robot/*Actor*  brought/*Predicate*  me/*Who*  an/*What*  orange/*What*  juice/*What* ."

I'm able to detect the Actor, Predicate, Where and When using Semantic Role Labelling. But I'm having problem with Who, What, How and Why.

**Is there a tool in nlp which identifies if a phrase in a sentence is an answer to which W-question?
How do I tell if a noun is a person or a thing?**

I know there is name entity recognition, but it only identifies proper nouns. So it only tells that Obama is a person, but not that teacher is a person.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looker for a part-of-speech tagger.
As you have already added a Standford-nlp-tag I give you the Standford-POS-tagger link:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml

For more details about how tagging is done take a look at the documentation. On basis on the tags you can answer your questions about Who/Whom/What etc..
In your case:
X brought Y an Z -> the article "an" determines that X is active/nominative, Y is passive/dative and Z is passive/accusative, while
X brought Y to Z for example would change things (Y acc., Z location)

By the way: a "thing" can be identified by comparison with a semantic network like WordNet if the model is not trained for the context.